# Return primitive value of Javascript Number

Tags: javascript

I have a simple String extension to convert to numbers:

`String.prototype.toInt = function(){ return parseInt(this); }`

Because it's rather difficult without comments to know what kind of value you are getting in JS, I want to protect myself if I try to cast a Number to a Number that I thought was a string. I thought this would work:

`Number.prototype.toInt = function(){ return this;}`

But this returns the entire function. I see that there is a `[[PrimitiveValue]]` property in Number that ideally I could return, but I cannot figure out how to access it (such as `this['[[PrimitiveValue]]']`)

Comment: You should not mess with these global prototypes! What makes `1.toInt()` better than `parseInt(1)`? You _already_ have this!

Comment: ^ That is not my question. Thanks for your concern

Comment: Use `valueOf`, but are you sure you have a number object?

Comment: It's not _concern_, this just strikes me as reinventing a wheel. Use your time productively.

Comment: Also, if you want to convert numeric strings to actual numbers you can use the `Number` function to do so.

Comment: @somethinghere It's fine. It's my application, and it took 20 seconds to write it.

Comment: @MinusFour I would be sure I have a number object. Otherwise it would not access `Number.prototype`. IE if I did `"123".toInt()` it would always be a `String`, and `123.toInt()` would always be a `Number`

Comment: Right, I thought you weren't modifying the Number prototype but using the String prototype. Anyway, what's wrong with `Number` to convert strings to numbers? Why do you need this?

Comment: @BarryBobes41 and it took you a couple of minutes to post to SO, and it takes you a couple of minutes to look at all the answers, to in the end conclude that what every is saying - it's unsafe to modify these - is true and give up. That's what I call a productive afternoon. Also, if you start building a bigger application and only notice the damage when you spent weeks building, then you will be cursing.

Comment: There is nothing wrong or right with any method. Is `"123".toInt()` easier to write that `parseInt("123")`? Yes. Is it better? No. It's just what I wanted to do.

Comment: @BarryBones41 There is something wrong and risky about modifying Javascript's `Number` and `String` objects.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37245051/how-can-i-directly-access-primitivevalue-value-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick for you:

```
Number.prototype.toInt = function (){ return this.valueOf(); };
```

Though I must say, modifying the prototypes of native objects (`Array`, `String`, `Number`, etc) has many downsides.  A functional approach is more flexible and fault tolerant, ie use `parseInt(value)` instead of `value.toInt()` would tolerate strings and numbers without issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your method is returning the value as a boxed Number instance, so you just need to cast it to a primitive. For example, using the unary plus operator:

```
Number.prototype.toInt = function(){
    return +this;
}
```