# How can I directly access [[PrimitiveValue]] value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to directly access [[PrimitiveValue]] of JavaScript Object types e.g. String or Number?

Comment: Directly access for what? Getting/setting values? Implementing new methods?

Comment: `String.prototype.toString()`, `Number.prototype.valueOf()`

Comment: Or in less code: `'' + stringObj` and `+numberObj`.

Comment: @Pointy— [*valueOf*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string.prototype.valueof) can be used for both. ;-)

Comment: I am aware of valueOf method to retrieve value from Primitive Object type. However I need to understand how JavaScript sets [[PrimitiveValue]] property for Objects. Is there a way to directly access it without using built-in methods such as valueOf()

Comment: [[PrimitiveValue]], if anything, is a term stemming from the ECMAScript reference, which describes the logic to ***implement ECMAScript***, not the userspace API. In other words, it's something that goes on behind the scenes and is important to people who write JavaScript *engines*, not to people who write programs in Javascript. – If that's not it, please clarify the context of this term and what exactly you need it for.

Comment: Your question states "how can I directly **access** [[PrimitiveValue]]", but your comment asks "how JavaScript **sets** [[PrimitiveValue]]". Those are two different things. The way to (in)directly *access* it is by arranging to have it coerced, as in `+numberObj`. The way it *sets* it is an internal affair that happens when you say `Number(42)`.

Comment: For those voting to close with the reason "unclear what you are asking", this question is not at all unclear. Why do you think it's unclear?

Answer (score 8):

> Is there a way to directly access `[[PrimitiveValue]]` of JavaScript Object types e.g. `String` or `Number`?

No, there's not.

The primitive value is obtained by JS when the object is used in a context which requires a primitive, and it does so by calling the `valueOf` method on the object. Contexts which require a primitive, as mentioned in the comments, include `+numberObj`, `'' + stringObj`, and "casting" via `Number(numberObj)`. Note that constructs such as `Object(false) && true` do **not** cast the boolean object to a primitive, nor does `if (Object(false))` (which therefore succeeds).

Note also `valueOf` can be overridden, in which case there are no cases when the underlying primitive value can or will be retrieved.

Answer (score 6):

No in a sense, because in regards the ES6 standard, [[[Primitive Value]]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toprimitive) is an internal conversion algorithm, not a result, taking an input value to be processed and an optional argument specifying the preferred type of the returned value. The algorithm is typically used in automatic type conversion and does not always return the same data type for a given input.

[[Primitive Value]] algorithms can be divided into standard and exotic. The standard approach is to default preferred result type to 'number' if not supplied. Exotic algorithms such as implemented for [Date Objects](http://www.ecma-internationa.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype-@@toprimitive) provide their own default value for conversion result.

Of course converting a String object into a string data type (e.g. "" + strObj) or a Number object into a number data type (e.g. +numObj) is trivial if and when needed. In most cases it is likely to done automatically for you.