# How the methods are called in ECMAScript class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```js
class Percentage
{
  constructor(percent)
  {
    this.percent = percent;
  }

  toString()
  {
    return `${this.percent}%`;
  }

  valueOf(){
    return this.percent / 100;
  } 

}

let fivePercent = new Percentage(5);
console.log(`${fivePercent} of 50 is ${50*fivePercent}`);
```

I am getting consoled with valid output. But Unable to understand how the "toString" and "valueOf" methods are called here?

Any one help me to understand?

Comment: I answered this a few years ago ([elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37246144/5217142)) although the question was closed. Technical detail of when and how the methods are used is described in [ECMAScript Standards](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toprimitive) (ECMAScript version 2015 linked)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use console.log, or perform any operation that implicitly converts an object to a string, javascript will call toString() on that object, if that method is defined.

So this expression:

```
`${fivePercent}`
```

Tells javascript to get the value of `fivePercent.toString()`.

Likewise, when you evaluate this expression:

```
50 * fivePercent
```

You're telling javascript to convert `fivePercent` to a numerical value, then multiply it by 50. If `valueOf()` is defined on the object, it will call that method to get the value; otherwise, the result will be NaN.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript calls the valueOf method to convert an object to a primitive value.
It automatically invokes it when encountering an object where a primitive value is expected.

You can read more about it in the below link 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf