# How to set a primitive value without losing object properties in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

Say (for reasons) I'm using object wrappers on primitive values, like this:

```
var x = new Number (7);
x.source = "never-you-mind";
console.log(x);
// Number {7, source: 'never-you-mind'}
```

How might I go about changing that primitive value without losing the object properties?

```
// do magic here
console.log(x);
// Number {777, source: 'never-you-mind'}
```

Or is it the case that the primitive value is immutable, and I need to construct a wholly new object-wrapped-primitive and then copy those properties across? (Which I'll probably do with a function).

Comment: I'm well aware that using object wrapped primitives are frowned upon by some/many. This question isn't about that.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to change internal `[[PrimitiveValue]]` slot for Number or String.

Comment: I just wonder personally, why do you need this format?

Comment: There's some primitive values being generated then modified per weird rules that are not functionally reversible, and there's an edge case where I need to revert back to the original values and start over. I could erect a whole other data structure to stash that background, but I'd rather just annotate the primitive values as I go, and at the end when all is good I can discard the annotations (a simple `let strippedObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(annotatedObj));` does that very neatly). There's more involved than that, but the gist of it is the elegance of associating metadata with values.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37245051/how-can-i-directly-access-primitivevalue-value-in-javascript